# shell prints line shell

Tags: shell, unix, computer-science

Write a script named `print_lines.sh` that uses `head` and `tail` together to print out a specific set of lines from a file. The script should take three arguments: the line number to start at, the line number to stop at, and the file to use. Here's an example run:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ print_lines.sh 7 10 /etc/passwd
shutdown:x:6:0:shutdown:/sbin:/sbin/shutdown
halt:x:7:0:halt:/sbin:/sbin/halt
mail:x:8:12:mail:/var/spool/mail:/sbin/nologin
operator:x:11:0:operator:/root:/sbin/nologin
```

In this example, the script prints line 7 through 10 (inclusive) of the `/etc/passwd` file. Your script must do error checking. Specifically, you need to check all the following things:

- You get the right number of arguments (3).
- The file specified exists and is a normal file.
- The first line number specified is less than or equal to the last line number specified.
- The actual number of lines in the file is greater than the last line to be printed.
- If any of those conditions are not true, you should print an appropriate error message to the user and stop. If they are all met, then you'll need to do a bit of arithmetic and use head and tail together to print out only the lines requested.

This is my work but it does not working good

```
filename=$1
firstline=$2
lastline=$3

i=0
exec <${filename}  # redirect file into our stdin
while read ; do    # read each line into REPLY variable
    i=$(( $i + 1 ))  # maintain line count

    if [ "$i" -ge "${firstline}" ] ; then
        if [ "$i" -gt "${lastline}" ] ; then
            break
        else
            echo "${REPLY}"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: 1. Format your post properly. 2. "It does not working good" is not descriptive; give us actual inputs, outputs, and error messages if any.

Comment: What about this doesn't work? It appears to work just fine. Though it doesn't use `head` or `tail` at all the way your assignment tells you to and it doesn't check for the expected error conditions.

Comment: Your ordering of the parameters is wrong, you do not check `$#`, you do not use `test -f ${inputfile} `, you do not compare first- and lastline, where is the `wc -l` for the total number of lines and you forget to combine head and tail with a pipe. Please shoot again (try to implement as much as you can).

Comment: The assignment tells you to use `tail` and `head`. I'm sure that would be much easier than looping over lines in a file.